# How to mention the filename inside the find command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How do I mention the filename in the Find command.

Example:

```
find . -name "*ESR*" | wc -l
```

I would like to mention the filename called "sample.txt" in the above example statement. Could you please help me with the syntax.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you mean by _mention the filename called "sample.txt"_, because it is trivial to call `wc -l sample.txt`, and it shouldn't be the real issue, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

`wc -l` does take filename as argument:

```
wc -l sample.txt
```

`find` should only be used when you want recursion, even then `wc` should be run within the `-exec` action of `find`, no need to use an extra anonymous pipe:

```
find . -name sample.txt -exec wc -l {} +
```

With `bash`, you can do the same with recursive traverse and globbing (`**`) via `globstar`:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -l -- **/sample.txt
shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

Comment: I also need to search for a string named ESR in the filename. Can I use the below statement ? find . -name sample.txt "*ESR*" -exec wc -l {} +